# Character ASCII issue in iOS11 keyboard

Tags: swift3, ios11, xcode9

I have an application in which I allow only characters to input with ascii value less than 127, Hence when I enter this ' character in textField, inside method `func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool` I get the ascii as 39, but later when I collect the string and just before sending my data to server I check the ASCII of the input string character by character, I get the ascii of ' character as 8216. This happens to me only in iOS 11 and not in previous versions of iOS

I check the release notes of iOS 11 it does not specify any thing related to this in its keyboard section. Is this a knnown issue. What should I do in such case, how to validate while enetering text in text field?

Comment: Please show the actual code causing the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Smart quotes and other features such as smart dashes are controlled via the [UITextInputTraits](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextinputtraits) Protocol which is adopted by both `UITextField` and `UITextView`.

Specifically, the `smartQuotesType` property can be set to one of `.default`, `.yes` or `.no` You should set this value to `.no`